# Is there compile warnings or errors for deprecated code in XCode for iOS4 projects by default?

Tags: xcode, ios4, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, deprecated

I took over an iPhone project recently that was developed prior iOS4. I'm wondering if XCode would prompt warnings or errors on compile. It currently succeeds with "No issues" when built so is it safe to assert that it contains no deprecated code? Or is there a setting to be set on XCode to warn on compile for deprecated code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting in Xcode to hide deprecated warnings: Go to Targets -> Your Target -> Get Info -> Build -> Warn About Deprecated Functions.
You can check if that setting is on (It's on by default) to make sure you're getting the "deprecated" warnings you want.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Build the project. Check the top most bar where your target and device are in XCode. Next to Running...xxtarget..on xxdevice is shown a yellow triangle with !(explanation mark)[image] . Click on that to get deprecations.